# adding media content to a Drupal Commons Group page header?

Tags: panels, 7

I've been playing with Drupal for a bit, and have gotten used to the idea of Content and fields.  I am now trying to use Drupal Commons 7 to up my game some and improve how my site looks.  Im a bit stumped however on how I can edit the look of my Group page.  Id like to add a big image at the top, before the group content.  I *think* this is done using panelizer but Im not sure.

First is this right?  Second, if so, where can I look for getting started tutorial type stuff that explains panelizer and how it works with the underlying field system?  Do I have to add a field to content somewhere?  If so, what and where?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by enabling the Media component and then adding its widget in the CKEditor configuration.